# Странные артефакты на мониторе

Tags: видеокарта, монитор, пк, артефакты

Конфигурация системы:

- Видеокарта: `AMD Radeon RX 5600XT`
- Процессор: `I3 10100F`
- Материнская плата: `B460 Asrock Phantom gaming`
- ОЗУ: `16 гб`.
- Блок питания: `600W Chieftec Proton`.

**Проблема:** пк подключён через `hdmi`. В одной игре под названием `Dead by Dailight` происходят странные вещи, сначала картинка замирает, я пытаюсь вызвать диспетчер задач, а оно начинает вызывать артефакты хотя пк работает, даже по дискорду говорить можно, было так только раз.

Но вот что происходит каждый день это спонтанные белые прямоугольники, как будто открывается новая вкладка но только в одном месте и это очень заметно!

Начиналось всё с одного белого пикселя, теперь уже узкий но длинный прямоугольник в самом верху. Происходит это недолго, около секунды, но каждый день и только в этой игре видеокарта работает на процентов `69`, ничего не греется и разгоном я не занимался, мощности блока питания хватает, драйвера все свежие, косяков при сборке не было.

Comment: Грешу на видеокарту, попробуйте проверить на другом мониторе, наблюдается ли проблема, если наблюдается, то проблема как раз в видеокарте, сдайте ее по гарантии.

Comment: Просто понимаете в чём вся странность. Артефакты идут редко и только в определенной игре (где-то раз в 2 часа) была бы вина видеокарты артефакты шли бы с самого начала загрузки Биоса, а так стрес тесты гоняет отлично и остальные игры, программы тоже

Comment: Думаю вина или монитора или кабеля. Потому что один раз кабель подключился "на горячую" но ни искр ни запаха не было хотя может повреждения какие то и пошли. Хотя с заземлением в доме всё ок

Comment: Так пробуйте, замените кабель, проверьте на другом мониторе, переустановите windows, проверьте целостность игры, разберите и соберите заново пк... Вариантов может быть много

Comment: У вас игра лицинзеонная? или пиратская?

Comment: Лицензированая конечно